# Stop youtube video autoplay

Tags: video, youtube, autoplay

I am using youtube video in "iframe" with height width src etc.
but it is playing auto. I want to play it with onclick. Please help me.

Comment: Is your IFrame pointing to the video on YouTube.com? e.g. <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/asdfSldfkj" /></iframe>

Comment: yes it is showing the same path

Comment: I posted the alternative to the `iframe` way to do it. You just use `object` and `embed` tags.

Comment: Add a transparent div on top of the YouTube video with CSS: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32601686/4455570

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To disable autoplay, just put **&autoplay=0** after the video ID so it looks like this:

```
<object width="425" height="350">
<param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/OdT9z-JjtJk&autoplay=0"></param>
<embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/OdT9z-JjtJk&autoplay=0" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="425" height="350"></embed>
</object>
```

http://support.google.com/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1181821

Updated code.

Answer (score 3):

It used to work. YouTube only verifies how to autoplay but they dont talk aboth NOT autoplay.

&autoplay=0
does not work.

http://support.google.com/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=171780&rd=1

Comment: You have to use the old embed code for the parameter to work.

Answer (score 1):

Jut put the "#t=XmXs" after the URL. NOTICE that you have to change the X to a certain time, such as 2m30s.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `autoplay=1 allow='autoplay'` and play video by click on link.

```
<a id="play-video" href="#">Play Video</a><br />

<iframe id="video" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/9B7te184ZpQ?rel=0" frameborder="0"></iframe>


$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#play-video').on('click', function(ev) {

   $("#video")[0].src += "&autoplay=1";
   ev.preventDefault();

  });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Add `&autoplay=0` to the video URL.

Comment: You have to use the old embed code for the parameter to work.

Answer (score -1):

With a code like this:

```
<iframe width="680" height="382" frameborder="0" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/n4K1Qpj1Ljg?list=UU3qGUTKOSIKbp08itEn8VIA?autoplay=0">
</iframe>
```

Answer (score -2):

Instead of using `&autoplay=false`, try using `?autoplay=false` regardless of whether there is a preceding `?rel=n`.

This seems to be working for me after getting it by trial and error.