# Prevent <iframe> auto load when opening the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have more iframe in my page to load the video.

Now I want to prevent the iframe auto load when I opening the page.
What is happening now is all iframe will load when I opening the page.

```
<div id="youtube-customers-add" style="float:left;width:60%;height:100%;">
        <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ivlfaPPP8TY" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
    <div id="youtube-customers-edit" style="float:left;width:60%;height:100%;">
        <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/8LupmPYSYIo" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
    <div id="youtube-dashboard" style="float:left;width:60%;height:100%;">
        <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/viCPPRHohSs" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
    <div id="youtube-finance" style="float:left;width:60%;height:100%;">
        <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/MYneEOIJYp0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
    <div id="youtube-finance-add" style="float:left;width:60%;height:100%;">
        <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/CEeuWTqjhQY" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
    <div id="youtube-finance-edit" style="float:left;width:60%;height:100%;">
        <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/p-NSAonIhgA" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
    <div id="youtube-payments" style="float:left;width:60%;height:100%;">
        <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/pURkv_rng-Y" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>  
    <div id="youtube-partslabor" style="float:left;width:60%;height:100%;">
        <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/5Ik7WVRxs7c" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
```

So, how can I prevent that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can rename `src` attribute

```
src-a="https://www.youtube.com/embed/p-NSAonIhgA"
```

I think you want to load iframe on some event, so you should use JavaScript, i think you need [jQuery when element becomes visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20487472/jquery-when-element-becomes-visible)

Comment: Tried but not function

Comment: @HiDayurieDave i think i found what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10861987/stop-youtube-video-autoplay

Comment: src-a wont work as the browser doesnt recognize attributes with a hyphen. We use such attributes in html5 or angularJS only. So to handle this attribute, you need to write a js for it.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are:

```
for (var i = 0; i < window.frames.length; i++) {
    if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer') {
        window.frames[i].document.execCommand('Stop');
    } else {
        window.frames[i].stop();
    }
}
```

Hope this help.